# Is it possible to add a JOIN to this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table and a query that I use to return a list of players who have scored the most goals.

The query works great, however in order for me to get the users' name I will have to perform another query based on the returned results (player_id).

Is it possible to amend my existing query as to join the two tables?  I know this is possible with a normal query, I'm just unsure whether it is in this instance because of the custom results table being returned.

This is my initial table, called `results`:

```
+----------------+-------------+-----+
| Field          | Type        | Key |
+----------------+-------------+-----+
| results_id     | int         | Pri |
| community_id   | int         |     |
| player1_id     | int         |     |
| player1_goals  | int         |     |
| player2_id     | int         |     |
| player2_goals  | int         |     |
+----------------+-------------+-----+
```

This is the query that I am using to return my results:

```
select player, sum(goals) from 
((select player1_id as player, player1_goals as goals from results where community_id = 5 ) 
union all 
(select player2_id as player, player2_goals as goals from results where community_id = 5 ) 
) p 
group by player 
order by sum(goals) desc
```

And this is how my results are being returned:

```
+----------------+------------+
| Player         | sum(goals) |
+----------------+------------+
| 2              | 94         |
| 14             | 63         |
| 7              | 43         |
+----------------+------------+
```

Is it possible to amend the above query and add a `join` to my `users` table:

```
+--------+-----------+
| id     | user_name  |
+---------------------+
| 2      | John       |
| 7      | Andrew     |
| 14     | Charles    |
+--------+------------+
```

To get an output of:

```
+----------------+----------------+------------+
|user_name       | Player         | sum(goals) |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
| John           | 2              | 94         |
| Charles        | 14             | 63         |
| Andrew         | 7              | 43         |
+----------------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: Are there only 2 players in a game?  Shouldn't each player have a row it a Players table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - yes, you can:

```
select u.user_name, sum(goals) from 
((select player1_id as player, player1_goals as goals from results where community_id = 5 ) 
union all 
(select player2_id as player, player2_goals as goals from results where community_id = 5 ) 
) p 
join users u on p.player = u.id
group by player 
order by sum(goals) desc
```

Comment: Excellent!! It worked! That's what I like a short answer to a long question! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a `join`.  You could also express this as:

```
select u.*,
       (select sum(case when u.id = r.player1_id then r.player1_goals else r.player2_goals)
        from results r
        where r.community_id = 5 and
              u.id in (r.player1_id, r.player2_id)
       ) as goals
from users u;
```